# Rspec not testing passing tests in regards to redirect

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, sinatra

I am in a bootcamp and I cannot seem to pass this test. The project is creating your bootleg version of twitter and the test is:

```
it 'signup directs user to twitter index' do
  params = {
    :username => "skittles123",
    :email => "skittles@aol.com",
    :password => "rainbows"
  }
  post '/signup', params
  expect(last_response.location).to include("/tweets")
end
```

My controller that handles this test is below:

```
 post '/users' do
    @user = User.create(params[:user])
    @error = @user.errors.full_messages

    unless @error == []
      redirect to '/signup'
    else
      session[:user_id] = @user.id
      redirect to '/tweets'
    end
  end
```

Basically what happens is that when I register a user and the data persists into the database my test should pass cause the expected `last_response.location` is to include `'/tweets'` and that is where
it redirects to. I don't understand why it's not passing.

Comment: can you inspect output of last_response in rspec code

Comment: I don't know what you're looking for but https://pastebin.com/ALBCSb5P

Comment: Nevermind I figured it out.

Answer (score 1):

Because the test was asking for post `/signup` and instead of using `/signup` as the route method name after the user posted the information to create the account I used `/users`. This caused the error.